# Como enviar objeto complexo para Web API?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, asp.net-web-api

Preciso passar um parâmetro para o meu Controller na Web API que é um objeto complexo, este objeto possui algumas propriedades normais (a mais complexa é um DateTime). Estou fazendo da seguinte forma, porém não consigo acessar:

WebApiConfig Route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithActionAndSkip",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{skip}",
                defaults: new { skip = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Local onde faço a requisição:

```
private CargaInicialHelper()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    }
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

ApiController:

```
public async Task<bool> RegistrarTerminal(Terminal terminal)
{
    return await ObterRespostaServicoAsync<bool>("RegistrarTerminal",
                                                    new HttpStringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(terminal),
                                                    Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8,
                                                    "application/xml"));
}
```

Onde obtenho a resposta enviada pelo Web API (sei que funciona pois neste local onde faço a requisição tenho vários outros requests sendo feitos (porém todos com variáveis normais) e todos eles funcionam):

```
private async Task<T> ObterRespostaServicoAsync<T>(string relativePath, HttpStringContent content = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            if (content == null)
            {
                request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(string.Format(URL, relativePath ?? String.Empty)));
            }
            else
            {
                request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(string.Format(URL, relativePath ?? String.Empty)));
                request.Content = content;
                var teste = await _client.PostAsync(request.RequestUri, content);
            }

            request.Headers.TryAppendWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(request.RequestUri);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string xml = Utils.RemoveAllXmlNamespaces(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)));

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

**Erro:**

> Bad request (500).  “Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity”

Comment: Não sou familiarizado com c# mas em java se você mandou um determinado content-type , no seu caso `application/json` você não deveria "anotar" o método que está recebendo esse content-type? No seu caso o `RegistrarTerminal`

Comment: @JorgeCampos não, não é necessário.

Comment: Já tentou fazer uma requisição com um *payload* em JSON feito na mão [usando isto](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez vc diz passar uma string como parametro que seria o JSON? Se for, sim.

Comment: Outra dúvida: você está desserializando um XML ou um JSON? Não está claro pra mim.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez basicamente xml. estava tentando com json também mas não consegui fazer funcionar em nenhum dos dois. Eu agora enxerguei um possível problema, onde monto o StringContent coloquei 2 parametros no construtor, o encondig.utf-8 e também um content-type application/xml. Mudou o erro, diz agora que "Value cannot be null. parameter name: entity"

Comment: Verifica como está a sua rota no `WebApiConfig.cs`. Outra coisa, o `terminal` está vindo nulo?

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithActionAndSkip",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{skip}",
                defaults: new { skip = RouteParameter.Optional });

Terminal não é nulo.

Comment: inseri a rota la em cima.

Answer (score 4):

Você está passando um valor arbitrário na URL da requisição - é possível que exista algum caractere que não seja suportado, ou que vá alterar a semântica da URL (e.g.: `.`, `:`, `/`).

Isso provavelmente é um sintoma de um problema maior - não use `[HttpGet]` (ou o verbo GET em geral) em operações HTTP que não sejam idempotentes, ou que precisam passar parâmetros complexos, ou que irão realizar alguma alteração no servidor. *Registrar*Terminal, pelo nome, deve fazer isso, então deve ser usado com um `POST` (ou `PUT`, dependendo da semântica da aplicação). Essas operações aceitam um corpo da requisição (*request body*), onde você pode passar o parâmetro (terminal) sem problemas.

Por exemplo, dado esse controlador:

```
public class ServicoController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("RegistrarTerminal/{nome}")]
    public bool RegistrarTerminal(string nome, Terminal terminal)
    {
        return terminal.Nome == terminal.Codigo;
    }
}

public class Terminal
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public int Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Você pode acessá-lo via o seguinte HTTP request:

```
POST http://localhost:50381/RegistrarTerminal/foo HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:50381
Content-Length: 82
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "nome":"Nome do terminal",
  "codigo":"TA:12/13&14",
  "valor": 3
}
```

Ou com o seguinte código C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:50381/RegistrarTerminal/foo");
        var reqBody = @"{
          'nome':'Nome do terminal',
          'codigo':'TA:12/13&14',
          'valor': 3
        }".Replace('\'', '\"');
        req.Content = new StringContent(reqBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var resp = c.SendAsync(req).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(resp);
        Console.WriteLine(resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
}
```

Note a criação do `StringContent` (ou do `HttpStringContent` no seu caso) - você deve passar o `Content-Type` naquele ponto. Você está usando o `TryAddWithoutValidation` para definir o Content-Type, e eu tenho quase certeza que essa chamada está retornando `false` (i.e., a operação não está sendo realizada). Isso faz com que o request saia com um `Content-Type: text/plain`, o que não é reconhecido pelo `Controller`, e isso causa a resposta `415 Unsupported Media Type` que você está recebendo.

Uma outra alternative é, depois da criação do `HttpStringContent`, você definir o seu Content-Type:

```
HttpStringContent content = ...;
content.Headers.ContentType = new HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Comment: é possível passar um exemplo com aquelas funções adaptadas para a forma que você falou? O problema que é o Get eu já sei, porém tentei inúmeras outras formas e não consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo configurar o content... preciso de um exemplo.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo do `Controller`.

Comment: preciso de um exemplo em C#, é possível?

Comment: o seu exemplo é de uma string e não te um tipo complexo. Vou alterar meu código, realizei algumas mudanças já porém ainda não funciona, esta dando erro 415.

Comment: `Terminal` é um tipo complexo (uma classe com 3 propriedades). O código, do jeito que está na sua pergunta, chega a compila? `ObterRespostaServicoAsync` recebe um string e um `HttpStringContent`, e você está chamando com duas strings...

Comment: Outra coisa - o código acima usa a classe `HttpClient` do System.Net.Http (NuGet Microsoft.Net.Http), e parece que você está usando o [Windows.Web.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.aspx); você teria que fazer algumas alterações (e.g., `new HttpStringContent(reqBody, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json")`), mas dá pra ter uma ideia.

Comment: Sim, foi feito isso. Mesmo antes de você postar. o que seriam estas alterações? O meu problema agora, como disse nos comentários acima explicando para o Cigano, é o seguinte “Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity”.

Comment: Onde está esse erro?

Comment: Quando passa pelo "PostAsync".

Comment: Você pode postar um [exemplo completo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que reproduza o seu problema? O seu código tem uma chamada a `PostAsync`, mas que usa um parâmetro, e a pergunta não mostra como ele é criado.

Comment: Não entendi o que você precisa saber. MAs vou alterar novamente o código.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30320/discussion-between-carlosfigueira-and-luiz-negrini).